# Simple PHP questions about hiding a input

Tags: php, forms, input, hidden

I want to hide a field of a form when number 1 has been chosen and is loaded in the databse.

The code gives no errors, but the field stays visible with number 0 and 1.

Somehow I can't get it right. It tried the following;

```
<?php
$query3 = mysql_query("SELECT `status`, `authcode` FROM `auth` ORDER BY `status` ASC LIMIT 1");
while($row3 = mysql_fetch_object($query3)){
?>
<tr>
<td><b>Authcode:</b></td>
<td>
<input name="authcode" type="text" value="<?= $row->authcode; ?>" <?php if($row->status == 0) ?> />
<input name="authcode2" type="hidden" value="<?= $row->authcode; ?>" <?php if($row->status == 1) ?> />
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*` functions, but MySQLi or PDO instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the `if` *around* the output you want to be conditionalized on it:

```
<?php if ($row3->status == 0) { ?>
    <input name="authcode" type="text" value="<?= $row3->authcode; ?>" />
<?php }
if ($row3->status == 1) { ?>
    <input name="authcode2" type="hidden" value="<?= $row3->authcode; ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I would just add that it looks like he should be using $row3 instead of $row.

Comment: Tried it with row3, but doesnt work. I saw the mistake of row-3 in your code and after changing that also doesn't work.

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't very meaningful. Is it getting errors? Is it displaying the fields when it shouldn't?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the `if` statement before:

```php
<?php if ($row->status == 1) ?>
     <input name="authcode2" type="hidden" value="<?= $row->authcode; ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Bamar and Pablo.

If you only want the hidden field once (row->status == 1), you could be more precise with something like:

```
<input name="authcode" type="<?php echo (($row->status == 1)?'hidden':'text') ?>" value="<?php echo $row->authcode; ?>" />
```

Cheers.